# Prevent Wappalyzer from identifying PHP framework

Tags: php, opencart

I am running an OpenCart application and noticed that Wappalyzer is able to identify the PHP framework used.

I checked the headers as well using HTTPLiveHeaders but it doesn't seem to show OpenCart anywhere. Also checked the cookies sent from my application with no success.

Does anyone know how to successfully prevent Wappalyzer from identifying the server side stack being used?

Comment: I don't know Wappalyzer, but imagine this is a hard problem to solve. I expect web-based apps like Opencart, Drupal, Wordpress etc will use tell-tale CSS strings that make it reasonably clear what web package is in use.

Comment: It's too effort for such IMO useless precaution. Better you should be interested in whether the OpenCart is secure enough platform than to try hiding it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy to solve, if you know the details Wappalyzer looks for. ;)

According to the [Wappalyzer Source Code on Github](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/7c8886ec3e4ed466ab2d326a7e9fe739f72aa701/src/apps.json#L4833) 
the identification of OpenCart is currently based on the following two things:

- the route - `?:index\\.php\\?route=[a-z]+/`
- "Powered By" - `Powered By <a href=\"[^>]+OpenCart`

So the answer is:

You can hide Opencart by altering your routing and removing the powered by message.

Keep in mind that this is a totally moving target.
They change the detections, you have to follow... spiral ahead.
From my point of view, it doesn't make sense to hide the tech.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens-André Koch, I had to enable seo urls on opencart backend and make sure that all products , categories , common pages and manufacturers used the seo keyword field in the backend. In order to verify you would have to uninstall wappalyzer and reinstall it on you PC, as I think it maintains a local list