# How to disable wappalyzer detection for opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using `opencart v2` and I can't find a way to prevent this sites to don't show my site as a `opencart`

I Use friendly SEO and my main page is HTML, So there is no Category nor route URL and certainly I have a `.htaccess` file and no powered by tags. Is there other ways for this problem?

Comment: It already answered. Check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25181797/5139148). Hope it works for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Wappalyzer from identifying PHP framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181607/prevent-wappalyzer-from-identifying-php-framework)

Comment: Checked Do u know how to remove account and other pages route?

Comment: @FairyDancer can u tell me how to change other pages like account?